# blank space on right side of website, culprit is not visible

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My website has blank space to the right of it almost as if a margin was added to the site. The site content stretches 100% across the site and looks good, but if you scroll to the right you will see the space whether you are on a desktop or mobile.

This is such an age old question which I have also encountered in the past, but in this specific scenario, I can not seem to figure out what is causing the extra space and or why it behaves the way it does.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `.leftside {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    /* left: 40px; */` - try left padding instead

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 1):

This block of code is causing the issue:

```
.hentry:after {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
display: block;
position: relative;
left: -5.1%;
width: 110.2%;
height: 1px;
}
```

Set the width to 100% or less. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

### Just simple add this in css file.

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```